# Personal Finance and Money Self-Evaluation -- Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :D

**Note:** This evaluation will close **14 September 2012** so be sure to get your answers in by then!

Comment: This is the 3rd exercise we are doing. Is it really helping the site? Also if we are randomly choosing the question and make these best, would it help?? Should'nt we be choosing the top 25 or 50 questions that come via search engine and try to make those better ... ie whats the point of making some questions better that no one may find ... the key parameter that this site is lacking is "Number of Questions per day" ... will doing this exercise help increase those number??

Comment: @Dheer I should have provided feedback from the team on the previous ones, though in general the idea of these is to have you guys take a look at *yourselves* and see if there are any weaknesses in your questions. Yes, there's only ten questions from the last 30-45 days, but the purpose is to say, "If a new user were to stumble across the site and see these ten questions, what would s/he think?" Finally, the Area51 scorecard is only *one* metric we use to determine graduation; all greens isn't a guarantee.

Comment: @Dheer That said, if you'd like to *just* look at the top 25-50 questions, you want to check out your Greatest Hits questions: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits

Comment: Re: *"Finally, the Area51 scorecard is only one metric we use"* .. and the other major one is, loosely, the idea of "ridiculous traffic growth".  Consistent traffic growth is the one we are missing, and I think it is due to a more competitive landscape for personal finance sites on the web.  Related to [WOOHOO! Seven Hundred Days in Beta!](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/578/woohoo-seven-hundred-days-in-beta) .. would be nice to see Stack Inc. comment on *that* post, while we take care of this homework below ;-)

Comment: Hey am I the only person who is going to vote on anything below? Come on people!  :-D

Comment: STAND DOWN REA!  I was busy!   Voting now...

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone! I'll be sure to get you some feedback as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 4):

[Why might I be declined when opening a new current account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16305/why-might-i-be-declined-when-opening-a-new-current-account)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question, good answer.  I learned something.

Answer (score 4):

[Pay off mortgage or invest in high value saving account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16310/pay-off-mortgage-or-invest-in-high-value-saving-account)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question.  I would prefer that the answer format a little better and draw a conclusion.  I read the answer, I agree, but it could have had a TLDR; summary that would be more helpful for new visitors

Answer (score 4):

[Do banks accept a large gift to me as a valid down payment for a house?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16232/do-banks-accept-a-large-gift-to-me-as-a-valid-down-payment-for-a-house)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: What a brilliant question.  I would vote to make the poster of this question the recipient of a cash prize.

Answer (score 3):

[Will the popularity of index funds cause a pricing bubble in the stocks that make up an index?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/will-the-popularity-of-index-funds-cause-a-pricing-bubble-in-the-stocks-that-mak)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: A nicely advanced question about personal finance with a well cited answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Are stocks only listed with one exchange in one place?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16309/are-stocks-only-listed-with-one-exchange-in-one-place)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Teetering on being a basic question and not an expert one, but well written and clear in the intent.  The answer was solid as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Can someone explain how government bonds work?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16295/can-someone-explain-how-government-bonds-work)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The title of the question doesn't really represent what the question is.

Answer (score 2):

[Archive Financial Records by Account or by Year](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16206/archive-financial-records-by-account-or-by-year)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question, but I think we can make a more authoritative answer.  Formatting on the answer here could make for a super answer to a great question with lots of search engine juice.

Answer (score 1):

[What is forward selling in terms of exchange rates?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16290/what-is-forward-selling-in-terms-of-exchange-rates)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[Getting payment from a moving sale via PayPal or by Bank of America account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16268/getting-payment-from-a-moving-sale-via-paypal-or-by-bank-of-america-account)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

[Credit History from ITIN to SSN](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16256/credit-history-from-itin-to-ssn)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The question could explain the acronyms more.